# Error PHP Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php, html

Al programar este codigo surge el siguiente error: `Undefined offset: 2`. 
¿Cual podrá ser la causa?

```
function checkCourt($fecha,$pista){
        //Entorno:
        $coincidencias;$fp;$nombre_archivo;$linea;
        //Algoritmo:
        $coincidencias=false;
        $nombre_archivo = "reservas.txt"; 
            file_exists($nombre_archivo);
            //Abrimos el handle
            $fp = fopen($nombre_archivo, "r");
            //Movemos el cursor al principio, por posible desajustes
            rewind($fp);
        while (!feof($fp) && !$coincidencias){

                $linea = fgets($fp);
                $linea=explode(" ", $linea);
                //strototime para convertirlo a date unix
                if(strtotime($linea[2])==strtotime($fecha)&&$linea[1]==$pista){

                    $coincidencias=true;

                }//Fin Si

        }//Fin Mientrasa
        fclose($fp);

            return $coincidencias;
    }//Fin Función
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que el problema está en la linea

```
if(strtotime($linea[2])...
```

seguro que una de las lineas del archivo que estás leyendo no tiene dos espacios, por lo cual, $linea no se crea como un vector de 3 posiciones.

Para evitar esto podrías modificar ese if por este otro

```
if (count($linea) > 2 && strtotime($linea[2])==strtotime($fecha) && $linea[1]==$pista)...
```

¡Suerte!